# How CSS Files are bundled in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, build, gatsby, styled-components, gatsby-plugin

I wanted to play with all different types of styling methods in GatsbyJS. In my project, I have three types of implementing stylings, `global CSS, CSS Modules and CSS-in-JS`(`styled-component)`. Everything works as expected. But, when I build the project with `gatsby build` and open one of the index.html where I did CSS-in-js I see that there is a CSS file in `data-href` tag inside. When I open it, It contains all the CSS stylings of my project. But I didn't even import it to the component where I did CSS-in-js. Why would something like this happen? Why stylings from `module.css` are being referred inside this file. [image]